# How to Code max(abs) in MATLAB

Tags: c++, c, matlab, max, mex

I have the following code in MATLAB which I am trying to rewrite in a mex file using C (or C++):

```
[a,b] = max(abs(C));
```

where C is a vector, a is the maximum absolute value of all the elements in vector C, and b is the index of a.

Please can anyone help me with the solution to this? I already tried to use "abs" function but it returned the positive integers (but I want them to remain double with their decimal values included). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description of what the Matlab code does is wrong. If `C` is a matrix, then applying `max` to it means `a` will be a row vector with each element containing the maximum value of the corresponding column of the result of `abs(C)`, and `b` will also be a vector containing the indices of the values in `a`. C and C++ are not the same language, so make up your mind about what you're using. If you'd used [`std::abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) you wouldn't have had the issue with truncation.

Comment: @Praetorian: `std::abs` will also truncate if you `#include <cstdlib>` and don't also `#include <cmath>`  It's just better to use `std::fabs` for this.

Comment: Thanks @Praetorian for your contribution. I've edited my question to highlight C as a vector. Because mex can compile both C and C++, anyone is fine by me.

Answer (score 4):

`man abs` tells you why you got that result: **abs** -- integer absolute value function

You want `fabs` here: "floating-point absolute value function". Note that you need to include `math.h` (`abs` is usually in `stdlib.h`).